# Using firebase-import results in "killed" with no explanation

Tags: firebase

Although I am able to upload a 5MB json file, I can't upload a 50MB json file using the command-line tool for uploading to firebase: firebase-import.

When I run the upload on the 50MB json file, it prints:

"

Reading ... [path to json]

Preparing JSON for import... (may take a minute)

Killed

"

It does not provide me with any more information. I testing this multiple times on a 5 MB file and had no issues.

The CLI's documentation states that this tool has been tested up until 400MB, so I do not think that this is a size issue. However, like I said, the only difference between the file that fails to upload and the file that uploads is the size.

Has anyone seen anything like this? Does anyone have any suggestions for diagnosing this? Thank you.

I have searched the web and SO for any similar questions but found none.

firebase-import --database_url [my url] --path [my path] --json [smaller file works here but larger doesn't] --service_account [path]

Expected: An upload progress bar followed by my data being visible on the firebase GUI.

Actual Result: A simple "Killed" with no information as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this is a memory limit issue. Since I am using an EC2 instance with low memory, preparing the json took up more space than available. Uploading via the GUI works fine for the 50MB file.